# Python : Copying directory tree with symbolic links in it

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, file-copying

In Python I am trying to copy a directory (actually, its the Jenkins jobs directory), but it contains symbolic links in it, when I copy I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BackupJenkinsJobs.py", line 272, in <module>
    main()
  File "BackupJenkinsJobs.py", line 208, in main
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(JenkinsJobSrc, cleanJobsDir, preserve_symlinks=False)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 163, in copy_tree
    verbose=verbose, dry_run=dry_run))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 163, in copy_tree
    verbose=verbose, dry_run=dry_run))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 167, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 148, in copy_file
    _copy_file_contents(src, dst)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 32, in _copy_file_contents
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\AutoRunTemplate\\builds\\lastFailedBuild'
```

I am using the following code:

```
try:
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(JenkinsJobSrc, cleanJobsDir, preserve_symlinks=False)

except distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError as e:
    print("Unable to copy Jenkins jobs. Error: %s".format(e))
    return
```

Any assistance would be appreciated on how to copy, ignoring the links, as preserve_symlinks doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Did you try using `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(JenkinsJobSrc, cleanJobsDir, preserve_symlinks=True)`

Default value seems to be `0` which is False.

Comment: @JRajan preserve_symlinks set to either True of False doesn't help.

Comment: #JRajan Changing it to true solved my problem. Thanks!